# Proc UCM (unobserved components model) equivalent of SAS in R

Tags: r, sas, time-series

Has anyone tried using package [dlmodeler](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlmodeler/dlmodeler.pdf) which seems to provide an equivalent of PROC UCM (SAS). Using structTS function is equal to running univariate PROC UCM. Can anyone tell me how to do a multivariate analysis using the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built a package which runs unobserved components model in R which depends on the KFAS package.
The package is available on [github](https://github.com/kaushikrch/rucm).